# How do I load instruments into EXS24 Sampler?

Tags: logic-pro

[image: EXS24 Sampler]

In the image above, when I hover over 'Drums and Percussion,' I find no instruments to choose from. Have I deleted any default files or folders? What is the source destination that the sampler gets the other instrument options from? I can clarify my issue if unclear. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**1.** Go to /Library/Application Support/Logic/EXS Factory Samples/03 Drums & Percussion and check whether there are any subfolders containing .wav files.

**2.** If so, create a new logic project and go to your library by clicking the library icon in the upper left corner of the logic window.

[image]

**3.** In the lower left of the library section, click the gear symbol and select "**Refresh library**".

[image]

Comment: What if I cant find a Logic folder in Application Support?

Comment: Where did you look? (There is more than one library folder)